# JSP inside JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp

How to write JSP code inside a jquery method. I want to call some JSP code in a jQuery method and use its result to manipulate DOM. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is code a jsp that gathers information (for example formatted as JSON).
Then use a jquery ajax call to call that jsp and use the data from the jsp to update the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kai. Here is the problem: I have written some code in jsp which calls a java method, computes and gives me back some result. Now what I want is to call this jsp code from my jQuery method  $(document).ready(function () , So that I can directly use the result to manipulate the DOM

Answer (score 0):

in you jQuery code use this:

```
$.get('ajax/myJSPpage.jsp', function(data) {
// do your DOM modifications here
  $('.employee').html(data.employees[0].firstName);

});
```

JSP file should return you some data. The best format is JSON as it is well supported in jQuery.

So just return a string similar to this

```
{
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Do I have to use Ajax? I mean isn't it possible to directly call jsp code from Jquery?

Like this:

 $(document).ready(function () {
<%
 createTree tree = new createTree();
 out.println(tree.constructTree());
%>

I mean if i directly call my java methods from Jquery.

Comment: I tried doing this. I am making an Ajax call to the (jsp and html page, I tried both). But nothing happens. I downloaded the ajax jar and copied it in my WEB_INF/lib folder.